# Can't execute KDE Dolphin from web-based PHP Script - but works for all other X programs

Tags: process, kde, php, background-process, dolphin

In a PHP script running under nginx/php-fpm, I can execute any X program using this PHP code:

`shell_exec("DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/nohup '{$command}' > /dev/null 2>&1 &");`

This will open the X program on my desktop, and the PHP script will carry on and finish.  The X program will stay open, even after the PHP script finishes.

It works for every single X program I've tried (including: mpv, kate, konsole, k3b and more) - but not Dolphin.  When trying to run Dolphin this way it never even appears at all, and no errors appear on screen or in any logs I can find.

Is there something different about how Dolphin is executed that could be relevant here?   Something to do with sockets/users/background processes or something like that?

I've checked the following already:

- Tried using the binary name only (dolphin) and full path (/usr/bin/dolphin) - all other programs work with both anyway, so doesn't seem to be a $PATH issue
- Executing the same command `DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/nohup '{$command}' > /dev/null 2>&1 &` in a Konsole shell works for everything, including Dolphin
- There's nothing in the PHP error log, and I've got all error levels enabled
- I've tried it both when other Dolphin windows are open, and when they're all closed (and confirmed there's no Dolphin processes still running)
- Nothing in the Xorg log either

Alternatively maybe there's some similar but different PHP code that would work for Dolphin?